# How to encrypt in javascript and decrypt in python?

Tags: javascript, python, cryptojs, pycrypto

I am trying to encrypt in javascript using cryptoJS and decrypt in python but some how I am unable to get this working.Here is my code :

```js
//encrypting in javascript using cryptojs
var message = "praveen";
var key = 'This is a key123';
var iv = 'This is an IV456';

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key, {
  iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
});

console.log(encrypted.ciphertext.toString()); // sending this over wire
```

```python
#decrypting in python

BLOCK_SIZE = 16
SEGMENT_SIZE = 128

def aes_decrypt(plaintext):
    key = 'This is a key123'
    iv = 'This is an IV456' 
    aes_mode = AES.MODE_CFB
    obj = AES.new(key, aes_mode, iv)
    ciphertext = obj.decrypt(plaintext)
    ciphertext = _unpad_string(ciphertext)
    return ciphertext
```

Comment: so, what doesn't work?

Comment: You switched the terms "plaintext" and "ciphertext" in your Python code.

Comment: does python expect a HEX string? : hint: no it does not

Comment: Please share the solution if you have got one